# using .not() with an exception is not working - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using toggle to show/hide two elements.
I am displaying a block with button link on toggle show.
I need to put an exception for toggle when the user clicks on button link.

My function with .not is not working.
I have tried with the code written below. Can you point me to where I went wrong.

```
  // On cache le block d'ajout au panier et l'image dans le block texte
  jQuery('.panier_block').hide();
  jQuery('.img_toggle').hide();

 // les cachés s'affichent et les affichés se cachent avec toggle.
  jQuery('.item').not('.btn-cart').click( function() {
      jQuery(this).find('.panier_block').toggle(275);
      jQuery(this).find('.product-image').toggle(275);
      jQuery(this).find('.product-image-subtext').toggle(275);
      jQuery(this).find('.product_info_sub_block_text').toggle(275);

  })
```

My HTML:

```
<li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
      <!-- <a href="#" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image" id="product-switch-<?php echo $z; ?>"> -->
        <div class="product-image" id="product-switch-<?php echo $z; ?>">
            <?php $_imgSize = 398; ?>
            <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                 src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                 alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
        </div>
      <!-- </a> -->

 <!-- Panier-->
  <div class="product_info_block panier_block">
    <div class="product_info_sub_block">

        <div class="product-info">
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
            <?php
            // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
            // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
            if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                    $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                    $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                    echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                }
            }
            ?>
            <!-- Affiche le poids-->
            <div class="block_weight_cat">

          <span class="weight_cat">
            <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
              $_weight = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getWeight());
                if ($_weight < 1)
                  $_weightstr = number_format($_weight*1000) . " mll";
                else
                  $_weightstr = number_format($_weight) . " cl";
              echo $_weightstr;
              ?>
          </span>
        </div>

            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
            <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


            <div class="actions">
                <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>

                <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
                    <a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('View Details')) ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a class="discover"href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="">En savoir plus</a> <span class="iconm-arrow_2">  </span>

        </div>
      </div>    <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
  <!-- <a href="#" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image" id="product-switch-<?php echo $z; ?>"> -->
  <div class="product-image" id="product-switch-<?php echo $z; ?>">
    <?php $_imgSize = 398; ?>
    <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
         src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
         alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
  </div>
  <!-- </a> -->

  <!-- Panier-->
  <div class="product_info_block panier_block">
    <div class="product_info_sub_block">

      <div class="product-info">
        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
        <?php
// Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
// Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
$_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
$_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
$_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
}
}
?>
        <!-- Affiche le poids-->
        <div class="block_weight_cat">

          <span class="weight_cat">
            <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$_weight = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getWeight());
if ($_weight < 1)
$_weightstr = number_format($_weight*1000) . " mll";
else
$_weightstr = number_format($_weight) . " cl";
echo $_weightstr;
?>
          </span>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <div class="actions">
          <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
          <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>

          <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
          <a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('View Details')) ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a>
          <?php else: ?>
          <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <ul class="add-to-links">
            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="discover"href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="">En savoir plus</a> <span class="iconm-arrow_2">  </span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- block de texte-->
  <div class="product_info_block bg_cat">

    <div class="product-image-subtext img_toggle" id="product-switch-<?php echo $z; ?>" >
      <?php $_imgSize = 398; ?>
      <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
           src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
           alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="product_info_sub_block product_info_sub_block_text">

      <div class="product-info">
        <h2 class="product-name product-name-cat"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
        <?php
// Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
// Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
$_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
$_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
$_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
}
}
?>
        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="text_describe_cat">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
            . Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
            in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</li>
      </div>


      <!-- block de texte-->
      <div class="product_info_block bg_cat">

        <div class="product-image-subtext img_toggle" id="product-switch-<?php echo $z; ?>" >
            <?php $_imgSize = 398; ?>
            <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                 src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                 alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
        </div>

        <div class="product_info_sub_block product_info_sub_block_text">

            <div class="product-info">
                <h2 class="product-name product-name-cat"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                <?php
                // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                    $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                    foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                        echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="text_describe_cat">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
        . Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          </div>


    </li>
```

Comment: Post the relevant HTML.

Comment: so you want but i'ts very long

Comment: Post the **relevant** HTML in your question, not in an answer. In the code you posted, there's only one element that has the `item` class, and one other element that has the `.btn-cart` class. Do you know what jQuery's `not` does?

Comment: Hi, please post the minimum amount of **html** required to reproduce the issue, all those php hieroglyphics make it very hard to read.  Please take the time to take the [tour] and read [mcve].

Comment: From your description, it looks like you want `jQuery('.item').find('.btn-cart')` - are you clicking the button? (when the user clicks the button)  Or do you want to click the `li`?  Click the `li` unless it contains a `btn-cart`?(which is what the code appears to be trying to do) - Can you describe in words what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

The [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method is used to "filter out" some elements from a collection.

The collection gathered by `jQuery('.item')` does not have any elements also having the class `btn-cart`...

That is why it looks like not working.

Comment: hum no, .item contains a .btn-cart

Comment: "contains" is not the same has also have the class.